# How to select two different input type text that is in a div?

Tags: html, css, input, text, selector

I have two different inputs of type text and I'd like to apply different styles to each of them. How would I go about doing that?

```css
div input[type=text] {
 background-color: #212121;
 border: none;
 color: white;
 padding: 1px 5px;
 text-align: right;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 10px;
width: 86px;
height: 35px;
}

.contact-field {
 width: 33.33%; 
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
}

.contact-field input {
 width: 90%;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 3px solid #dedede;
 outline: none;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 transition: all .325s;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <input type="text" name="MAR 7" value="MAR 7">
 </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="caption">
    <h5>Ziggo Dome</h5>
    <h6>NIEUW-AMSTERDAM, NETHERLANDS</h6>
    </div>
 </div>

  <div class="main-container">
    <section class="contact-container"> 
      <form method="GET" action="#">
        <div class="contact-field">
           <input type="text" name="full-name" placeholder="Email Address" required/>
 </div>
```

I am clearly new to this. I hope that you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the css, to target the first input you'd do something like this - `.row .column input[type="text"]`

And the second one like this - `.main-container .contact-container form contact-field input[type="text"]`

This'll allow you to apply different css styles to your each of your inputs, without them crossing over.